# Why is NAN unequal to everything except true, in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point

In PHP, `NAN` compares false to `0`, `"0"`, `false`, `array()`, `array(1)`, `NAN`, `null` and basically every other class of variable I could discern.

But `NAN == true` returns `true`. Why does `NAN == true` return `true`?

Comment: `gettype(NAN);` returns `double`.

Comment: @Aaron: I was seeing how it reacted to other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NAN (quite NAN or signaling NAN) is a non-zero floating point value.
*** That is why ***

```
sqrt(-1.0) -> NAN
```

There is -NAN and +NAN although since about 80286, it is just usually recognized as NAN on test.

Check your FPU floating point instruction set if you need to.

+INF and -INF are also non-zero floating point values:

```
- log(0.0) -> +INF
log(0.0) -> -INF
```

Here is a dump of the Intel floating point stack. I'll just list the few values I was talking about: (don't forget, internally, FPU is 10 bytes):

```
     <exp>  <mantissa>
0.0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
-INF FF FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
+INF 7F FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
-NAN FF FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
+NAN 7F FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So as you can see, only 0.0 is ZERO!

Comment: This sounds like the most sensible interpretation, an abstraction leak though it also is.

Answer (score 9):

In php, `$x == true` is the same thing as `$x? true : false`. That is, comparing equal to `true` with `==` and not `===` means that `$x` will evaluate to true in a boolean context.

If `NAN` were to evaluate to false in a boolean context, `NAN == false` would evaluate to true instead.

Comment: @alex: hell if I know. The php docs are pretty poorly organized.

Comment: But wouldn't `NaN == false` make _more_ sense? I'm not convinced that you've fully answered this!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, why would it make more sense? I'm not talking about sense, but what actually happens.

Comment: The OP asked /why/, i.e. what happens and why did someone think it makes sense?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I already answered what happens, and it makes more sense than being inconsistent with what `== true` means for the rest of php.

Comment: @habnabit: The rest of PHP isn't NaN. By your logic, `0` should loosely compare to `true` because "some other values do".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, huh? All I've said is that if `$x` evaluates to true in a boolean context, `$x == true`. I'm not sure who you're quoting with '"some other values do"', either.

Comment: @habnabit: I'm simply pointing out that NaN is not like your other `$x` values. You can't claim that it makes sense for `NaN == true` solely on the basis that some other values `== true`. `NaN` is its own beast, and it is not the same as a number, string, boolean or any other thing you might come up with. It's not even equal to itself. On _that_ basis, I believe it makes more sense for `NaN == false` and in that regard you didn't present a clear argument as to **why** this is not so.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason `is_numeric(NAN)` returns `true`.

Comment: That is so awesome! For real, I am giggling right now and no one has a clue why.

Comment: Heh, such a subtle sense of humour... _is_numeric(not a number)_

Comment: Which makes sense once you realize `NAN` is of type `double` (float).

Answer (score 1):

I think they fixed it in later version of PHP.
I am using 5.2 and NAN is actually equal to false.

here is my code

```
<?php
var_dump(PHP_VERSION); //string(6) "5.2.17"
if(NAN == false)
{
    echo "false";
}

if(NAN == true)
{
    echo "true";
}
//This only print out "false".
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure? You must be using strict comparisons, no?

Comment: Nope, I use the == operator. Edited my post ... hmm... Looks like I'm the one getting the weird result here...

Comment: Mine is 5.3.3-7 on Debian and returns true

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `==` operator is "operands are equal after type juggling" (as opposed to `===` which means "operands are equal and have the same type"). You can look up the exact (and rather arbitrary) rules [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types), but when one of the operands is numeric, type juggling can take three forms:

1. the other operand is a boolean or null -> both sides converted to boolean and compared
2. the other operand is an array or an object -> never equal, no type juggling is done
3. the other operand is a string, number or resource -> it is converted to a number and compared

So in case 2. the result is false by definition, in 3. it is false because NAN compared in any way to any numeric value is false, and in 1. NAN is converted to boolean, which is true ([rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), but basically anything other than zero/null/empty is true), so the comparison will be true if the other side is true as well.